Is it possible to get a second chance at college?
I graduated highschool in 2009. I started community college right out of highschool. I got 4.0 my first semester. After that my grades began to drop over time as well as "withdraw" from a few classes. Maybe 3? I strung college along with me through my substance abuse. On and off for probably 10 years. Needless to say, my grades sucked. Also, I was working on a couple different things in college. One was obtaining an AA in American sign language (which I am about 2 semesters away from completing) and I was taking the prereq's for transferring to an UC to go into veterinary medicine. I even completed the honors transfer program (but didn't transfer.) So...now that I am in recovery and I'm in a new phase of my life, I want to go back to school. Not for either of my past endeavors though. I am very interested in Cognitive Science and Human-Computer Interaction. A lot of these old classes that lower my GPA don't even pertain to my new major. I'm worried about my past interfering with potential to succeed. I'm also concerned about my situation with financial aid due to multiple (w)s. Has anybody been/know somebody in a situation like mine? What was the outcome? I'm lost on where to begin. Can I get classes just removed like they never happened?

Best of luck on a fresh start in 2025. What does life look like, as best you can imagine at the moment, following your Cognitive Science or Human-Computer Interaction studies?

Undergraduate admissions is off topic here, see https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300

But, yes, many schools explicitly encourage ’non-traditional’ or ‘adult learner’ students. (My nearby state university is actually majority ‘non-traditional’, begging the question of just what traditional is).

Basically, you select an institution that you are interested in and fill out an admission form, just as you would have done when you first went to college. Most institutions have admission paths for students who (i) are not straight out of high-school, or (ii) have undertaken some other educational path such as a trade, or (iii) did not successfully complete a previously-attempted college/university education.
After that, it's very much up to the individual institution how they will view your particular combination of high-school results, abandoned or flunked-out prior college education, and life experience.
Don't be deterred. You have very little to lose except time in applying.

This is dead on. I would encourage you to apply to community colleges now; maybe it's not too late for you to start taking classes in Spring 2025. Sooner is better; later often turns into never. And then you can apply to the institutions of your choice in Fall 2025 or Spring 2026.
